# Multiple nested loop

Tags: php, loops

Can anyone explain me the working of multiple nested loops with some suitable  example in php?
Actually, i know that how the loop inside another loop works but i don't know about how the loop inside the loop of another loop works.
For example i am trying to understand the code given below but unable to understand it's working.

```
<?php
for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--){
  for($k=6;$k>=$i;$k--){
    echo " &nbsp;";
  }
  for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
    echo "* &nbsp;";
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--){ // means this loop will start from i=5 and run till i >= 1
  for($k=6;$k>=$i;$k--){ // now this loop will starts from 6 and run till k > i ex. in first loop k will run for k=6 and k=5
    echo " &nbsp;";
  }
  for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){ // this loop will starts from 1 and run till j <= i value
    echo "* &nbsp;";
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

**i = 5**

k=6 "&nbsp";

k=5 "&nbsp";

k = 4 // now terminate as k >= i false

j = 1  "*&nbsp";

j = 2  "*&nbsp";

j = 3   "*&nbsp";

j = 4   "*&nbsp";

j = 5  "*&nbsp";

j = 6  // now terminates as j <= i false

**i = 4**

so on .....

Answer (score 0):

**Try to debug the flow yourself:**

The main loop `$i` will looping for 5 times (5 to 1). For each `$i` the inner first loop `$k` will looping for various times depending on the condition and same for the next loop. Check the Result and debug yourself.

```
for($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--){
    echo '$i with $k Started:<br/>';
    for($k = 6; $k >= $i; $k--){
        echo $i." - ".$k."<br/>";
    }
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    echo '$i with $j Started:<br/>';
    for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++){
        echo $i." - ".$j."<br/>";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

**Result:**

```
$i with $k Started:
5 - 6
5 - 5


$i with $j Started:
5 - 1
5 - 2
5 - 3
5 - 4
5 - 5

$i with $k Started:
4 - 6
4 - 5
4 - 4


$i with $j Started:
4 - 1
4 - 2
4 - 3
4 - 4

$i with $k Started:
3 - 6
3 - 5
3 - 4
3 - 3


$i with $j Started:
3 - 1
3 - 2
3 - 3

$i with $k Started:
2 - 6
2 - 5
2 - 4
2 - 3
2 - 2


$i with $j Started:
2 - 1
2 - 2

$i with $k Started:
1 - 6
1 - 5
1 - 4
1 - 3
1 - 2
1 - 1


$i with $j Started:
1 - 1
```